# Prove $A$ is creative set

Tags: computability

Let $\varphi_i$ be the $i$-th partial function of our enumeration. Consider the set 
$$ A = \{ y \in \mathbb{N} \mid \varphi_{\mathrm{fact}(y)}(y) \downarrow \} $$
I have to prove this set to be [creative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_and_productive_sets). $A$ is [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) because its semi-characteristic function can be implemented through the algorithm:

```
function is_element_in_a(y):
    u = fact(y)
    if varphi_u(y) terminates then
        output(true)
    end
```

Then, $A$ is creative because its complement $\bar{A}$ is a productive set. We can prove $\bar{A}$ to be productive through [many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction):
$$ \{ x \mid \varphi_x(x) \uparrow \} = \bar{K} \preceq \bar{A} $$
$$ \bar{K} \preceq \bar{A} \iff K \preceq A \iff \left( \exists h \text{ total function such that } x \in K \iff h(x) \in A \right) $$
How can I prove this?

## My attempt

Consider the partial recursive function
$$ \psi(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, x \in K \\ \uparrow, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
which can be specialized through the [s-m-n theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem) to the function
$$ \forall y \quad \varphi_{h(x)}(y) = \psi(x,y) \text{ for fixed } x $$
where $h$ is a total recursive function. Then 
\begin{align*}
x \in K & \to \varphi_{h(x)}(\,\cdot\,) \downarrow \; = 1                  
  & x \not\in K & \to \varphi_{h(x)}(\,\cdot\,) \uparrow \\
  & \to \varphi_{\mathrm{fact}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)))}(\,\cdot\,) \downarrow 
& & \to \varphi_{\mathrm{fact}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)))}(\,\cdot\,) \uparrow \\
  & \to \varphi_{\mathrm{fact}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)))}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(g(x))) \downarrow 
& & \to \varphi_{\mathrm{fact}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)))}(\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(g(x))) \uparrow \\
  & \to \mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)) \in A
& & \to \mathrm{fact}^{-1}(h(x)) \not\in A 
\end{align*}

but I'm not really sure I can use $\mathrm{fact}^{-1}$ like that because factorial is not bijective function ($\mathrm{fact}^{-1}(y)$ may not exists).

Comment: Unfortunately it's important to know exactly what enumeration $\langle \phi_e\rangle_e$ of partial functions is if you're going to apply the factorial function to the index. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @realdonaldtrump thank you for your comment. I think I can find an enumeration function. I will add it as soon as possible. However, how does the solution depends on the enumeration function?

Comment: If for example $\phi_{2n}$ always enters an infinite loop for all even numbers $2n$, then evidently $\phi_{\mathrm{fact} (y)}(y) \uparrow$ whenever $y \geq 2$. So some more information is needed. Another possibility is that 'fact' is meant to be something other than the factorial function, though I have no guess as to what.